# vuejs - template, store, this.$store is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, syncfusion

I have a problem retreiving the vuex store in a vuejs component.
My architecture is pretty straight-forward. I have a store with two modules.

main.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  },
```

Events.vue - Here I use my custom component UserDropdown in a syncfusion component, but I dont think that's relevant. The first registers the UserDropdown, the second fragment will be called when you click on a cell and returns my custom component:

```
...
components: {
            UserDropdown
        },
...
editTemplate: function () {
   return {template: UserDropdown}
},
...
```

UserDropdown.vue - here I'd like to use the store, but the result is: "this.$store is undefined". Access to the store from within other components like Events.vue  works just fine.

```
computed: {
        users: function () {
            return this.$store.state.usersState.users;
        }
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import projectsState from './modules/projectsStore'
import usersState from './modules/usersStore'
import createLogger from 'vuex/dist/logger'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    projectsState,
    usersState
  },
  strict: debug,
  plugins: debug ? [createLogger()] : []
});
```

Why doesnt that work? Is the problem related to the "template: UserDropdown"? I thought every component should be able to access the store...

Comment: How do you import `store` in `UserDropdown` component?

Comment: How did you setup your store? Can you provide your full main.js and whatever is imported to set the `store` in the main.js. Have you called `Vue.use(Vuex)`?

Comment: Frank Provost - I added the store.js to my post.
@cccn - I dont import store in UserDropdown, the store should be available everywhere, when you write the segment as shown above in main.js. That wokrs just fine in all my components but UserDropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it looks, one has to import the store once again in the UserDropdown.vue component. That doesn't make any sense to me, since I imported the store in the new Vue instance as shown above.
Here the code fragments to be added in the UserDropdown.vue

```
...
import {store} from "../store/store";
...
export default {
    store,
    name: 'UserDropdown',
...
...mapGetters({users: 'usersState/AllUsers'})
...
```